# Insert new paragraph in XWPFDocument (C# NPOI.OOXML)

Tags: c#, npoi

I am trying to use `XWPFDocument.InsertNewParagraph(XmlDocument cursor)` but the method is asking for `XmlDocument cursor`, and I don't know where to find it, or what to use.

All the documentation I have found on internet is about the Java version of the library, and says to use `XWPFParagraph.getCTP().newCursor()`, but there is no method named `newCursor` in the object returned by `getCTP()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of the NPOI I found that the package didn't implement `InsertNewParagraph` / `InsertNewTbl` / `IsCursorInTableCell` methods of the `XWPFTableCell` which receives the argument type `XmlDocument` but the name is cursor (it is also strange). Below is my suggestion:

Call `AddParagraph`, create run(s) `(IRun)` inside it, at the end call `SetParagraph` instead of `InsertNewParagraph`.

Comment: SetParagraph overrides whatever paragraph is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it

```
//Assumes it's currently the last paragraph, as in - just created
void insertParagraph(XWPFDocument doc, XWPFParagraph par, int pos)
{
    var idx = doc.GetPosOfParagraph(par);
    for (int i = idx; i > pos; i--)
    {
        doc.SetParagraph(doc.Paragraphs[i - 1],i);
    }
    doc.SetParagraph(par, pos);
}
```

This is intended to be called after first adding the new paragraph to the end with doc.CreateParagraph(), but the basic idea is to shift every paragraph down by one, starting from end, until the desired position. Then set the new paragraph in that position.